# Definitive documentation/API for Android gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Where can I find the definitive documentation for the Android gradle plugin? By definitive, I mean not a [user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) that shows examples of how to use it, but something similar to an API doc for Java. For example, if I want to know what the `Activity.onCreate()` method does, I can look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate-android.os.Bundle-) to see everything it represents, all the acceptable parameters, and every way I can interact with it. If I'm not satisfied with that, I can even go further to the [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java;drc=master;l=1562?q=android.app.Activity%20&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject).

The Android Gradle plugin on the otherhand seems like a black box to me and the gradle sync and build errors within Android Studio often seem less than helpful. In the [build-files user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#build-files) they link to the [DSL reference documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html) but I'm finding it hard to relate this to what I'm actually seeing in the gradle.build files. For example in the following `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            isDebuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

where can I find the api style documentation for what `android`, `defaultConfig`, and `buildTypes` represents? Where do I find the documentation or code that would allow me to know every possible entry/field/parameter I can use within these sections? I.e. other than picking and choosing from the user guides, how would I know I can put `buildTypes` section within the `android` section, and how can I know the naming restrictions of my buildType names, or what the boolean or other fields within the buildTypes are?

The problem of not having a definitive reference is exemplified by the typo in the above code, where `isDebuggable true` should be `debuggable true` despite being taken directly from the [User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types). Where can I refer to know the correct names of these fields, and what values they accept as parameters?

#### Edit

I see until version 3.4 there was [this documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html) which is showing exactly what I am looking for. I am unable to navigate to a similar doc within the [newer version documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/classes)